# Is there a colloquial phrase to describe a sports heckler?

Tags: terminology, colloquialisms

What might you call someone who verbally harasses a player from the stands?

> Hey Lincecum. I've seen better curves on a square!

Who is that guy?

Comment: We would just call him a jerk (well, something more nasty) but you get the idea.

Comment: Search "sports heckler" in Google and it returns many hits on that phrase.  Why do you think there is another name for that person?

Comment: Well, colloquialisms make for a more interest narrative. I could call someone a infantryman, by I might prefer to describe them as a "grunt". Colloquialisms often exist to provide more visually evocative descriptions of the activity. (Grunt? Ah yes -- he must spend his time schelping a backpack and grunting.)

I Googled for this before posting, but didn't find anything interesting. 

I wish there was a dictionary of colloquialisms. Urban dictionary is a good source, but only if you know the phrase you're looking for -- their thesaurus features leave a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heckler#Sport) *heckler* is still the proper term.

If it is heckling between players, we call this *trash talking*.  (Or Wikipedia suggests *sledging* when it is between cricket teams.)

The other term for this guy is *jerk* (or any variety of nastier nicknames).

Comment: Infantryman is also a proper term. I might prefer grunt. 

What's the analogous phrase here?

Comment: @user48956 I understand your point.  I cannot seem to find any reference to any other term for this.  We in the States typically refer to these people as *obnoxious fans*, but that seems too general for your context.